# PHP dropdown value

Tags: jquery, html

I have a function as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#payment-form").submit(function(event) {
        // disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $('.submit-button').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        // createToken returns immediately - the supplied callback submits the form if there are no errors
        Stripe.createToken({
            name: $('.card-name').val(),
            number: $('.card-number').val(),
            cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
            exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
            exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
        }, stripeResponseHandler);
        return false; // submit from callback
    });
});

if (window.location.protocol === 'file:') {
    alert("stripe.js does not work when included in pages served over file:// URLs. Try serving this page over a webserver. Contact support@stripe.com if you need assistance.");
}
```

I also have a form containing inputs as follows:

```
<input type="text" size="2" class="card-expiry-month" /> <span>/</span>
```

I can get the value of the in card expiry month, but whn i try to change it to a dropdown as below the form wont submit

```
<select id="expiration-month" class ="card-expiry-month"
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm confused. Where is the PHP?

Comment: Did you close your opening `select` tag?

Comment: yes but did not paste properly

Answer (score -1):

Try

$('#expiration-month :selected').val();

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#clickable").click(function() {
            alert($('#expiration-month :selected').val());
        });
        });
    </script>
    <div id='clickable'> Click Me </div>
    <select id="expiration-month" class ="card-expiry-month">
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
```